# Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-rc-1-all.zip'

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1 Canary 15) on macOS Big Sur.
Last week I worked on a project, and so far it went fine.

I opened it again today, and greeted with this message:

> Could not install Gradle distribution from
> 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-rc-1-all.zip'.

Here's my build.gradle:

```
#Wed Jul 01 22:54:14 ICT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-rc-1-all.zip
```

I'm not sure if internet connection is the cause, because if the link is opened on browser, a download pop up appears. So I delete `$HOME/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0-rc-1` folder and replace it by unziping gradle-7.0-rc-1-all.zip. Then try re-syncing the project again. Doesn't work.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 2):

OK finally I found the culprit.
Go to Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment.
Then click Gradle and check Gradle user home.

Mine was `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-16.jdk`.
I believe I accidentaly changed that when messing with various JDKs on Android Studio.

So I installed gradle (`brew install gradle`) then changed Gradle user home to `/usr/local/opt/gradle/libexec/`). Now I can build all my existing Android projects without problem.

Comment: This had me frustrated for hours! Thank you for finding this !!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced exactly the same problem with the same error message, some weeks before, while using a not so stable internet connection. I ended up repeating the process many times, until after a lot of tries and a lot of time spent, I was lucky enough and it installed successfully.

So, my solution is to try to repeat this process using a more stable internet connection, otherwise something is corrupted and the installation fails.

Comment: Doesn't work. Uninstalled the Canary, then installed the last stable version (4.2). Switched to wired connection, WiFi was turned off, no VPN/firewall etc enabled. This happens on all projects, e.g `The cached zip file /Users/anta40/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.8.2-all/446le5pselpgh0bzinc35sp0d/gradle-6.8.2-all.zip may be corrupted.`. What to do, then?